# How do I transpose data from a 1D Array to a 2D array of objects and change some elements?

Tags: typescript, multidimensional-array

In Typescript:

I have a 1D array of objects: `my1dArray`.

I am copying 5 x each row of `my1dArray` into a 2D array `my2dArray` (so I end up with a `my2dArray[3][5]`).

I then reset the id element for each row of the `my2dArray`.

For `my2dArray[0]`, I end up with this (id=4):

```
{id: 4, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 4, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 4, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 4, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 4, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
```

What I thought I would get is this:

```
{id: 0, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 1, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 2, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 3, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
{id: 4, surname: "Smith", givenNames: "Linda"}
```

The rest of the `my2dArray[4][5]` array has the same problem.

What am I doing wrong?

```
//Create 1d Array
let my1dArray: any[];
my1dArray = [

      { id: 0, surname: 'Smith', givenNames: 'Linda'},
      { id: 0, surname: 'Bloggs', givenNames: 'Bill'},
      { id: 0, surname: 'Jones', givenNames: 'Jim'},

];


//Initalise 2d Array
let my2dArray = init2DArray(3, 5, function () {

      return 0

});


let j = 0;
let k = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < my1dArray.length; i++) {

      for (let count = 0; count < 5; count++) {

          my2dArray[j][count] = my1dArray[i];
          //reset the id
          my2dArray[j][count].id = k;
          k++;
      }



    j++;

}

console.log('myNewData', my2dArray[0]);




/////Intialisation function///////////////

function init2DArray(xlen, ylen, factoryFn) {

      let ret = [];

      for (let x = 0; x < xlen; x++) {
          ret[x] = [];
          for (let y = 0; y < ylen; y++) {
              ret[x][y] = factoryFn(x, y)
          }
      }

  return ret
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you don't copy each row of `my1dArray`. This assignment:

```
my2dArray[j][count] = my1dArray[i];
```

only fills `my2dArray` with references to the same object in `my1dArray`. Therefore when you change the `id` you do this for the same object every time in your inner loop.

To correctly copy an object in JS you may want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/how-do-i-correctly-clone-a-javascript-object). For shallow copy (sufficient for your example code) you can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

Below a working code snippet:

```js
//Create 1d Array
let my1dArray: any[];
my1dArray = [{
    id: 0,
    surname: 'Smith',
    givenNames: 'Linda'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    surname: 'Bloggs',
    givenNames: 'Bill'
  },
  {
    id: 0,
    surname: 'Jones',
    givenNames: 'Jim'
  },
];


//Initalise 2d Array
let my2dArray = init2DArray(3, 5, function() {
  return 0
});

let j = 0;
let k = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < my1dArray.length; i++) {
  for (let count = 0; count < 5; count++) {
    my2dArray[j][count] = Object.assign({}, my1dArray[i]);
    //reset the id
    my2dArray[j][count].id = k;
    k++;
  }
  j++;
}


function init2DArray(xlen, ylen, factoryFn) {
  let ret = [];
  for (let x = 0; x < xlen; x++) {
    ret[x] = [];
    for (let y = 0; y < ylen; y++) {
      ret[x][y] = factoryFn(x, y)
    }
  }
  return ret
}

console.log(my2dArray)
```